# What error should be returned if response don't return expected field?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, http-error

Suppose you send a request to an endpoint and expect to receive a record array field as response, like this:

```
{
"records": [
...
],
}
```

Now you are processing the `response.data.records`, but then you find out the `records` array field is not present.

Should I throw an exception? If yes, what would be the best status code to describe this error?

Consider that a request was correctly formatted and sent to the endpoint.

When I receive a proper response, I'm iterating over the array and searching for a specific object. In this case, I return a `404` when the object is not found.

But here I don't even have the `response.data.records` array to iterate.

Comment: This is largely a matter of opinion and thus off-topic for SO, but that looks like a *bad request* to me, for which there's a specific HTTP status code: [400](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-400-bad-request).

Comment: Normally the API Endpoint defines the result response, which should be fixed for the endpoint, unless it reacts to provided parameters and returns a specific result. But if you access an API Endpoint it should always return a consequent response/data structure to rely on. If a request, would return a response, in which the response/data structure could not be returned, the Server itself should respond with an HTTP-Error according to the issue. Which would be either HTTP-Status code 400 or if no matching Resource could be found, the HTTP-Status code 404 might be sufficient.

Comment: But that would mean the request was somehow wrong, right? The point here is that the response is not as expected for some reason. We can assume the request was rightly formatted.

Comment: It might be OK to go with 500 if this is happening due to resources missing on "server-side" to process, that is **not affected by client's request**.  
If the record is requested by server due to client's request (e.g. client requesting server to iterate over client's queried records (= server is querying with client's query)). Then, I think it is safe to go with 404 since that is clearly server is missing stuff that **client requested**.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking. Returning a 500 might seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you don't expect a request to be the way that it has arrived, you could use a `400 - bad request`. According to [Mozilla MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

> 400 Bad Request -
> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Because, 404 is normally used when you couldn't find a resource.

Comment: In this case the request was correctly sent. Is it still valid to use a 400?

Comment: Ohhh I get it. If you are working with the client, you are not supposed to return any status code. According to a client - server architecture, you would just have to notify the user that there are no results for this request.